# CS0103 error in Workflow Engine

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, workflow-engine

I’m trying to integrate my own business logic into [Workflow Engine](https://workflowengine.io) .NET. In particular, I want to get the responsible employee from my business logic and send him an email. Here’s a piece of code in Code Action where the problem is:

```
var responsibleEmployee = AsperIo.EmployeeProvider.GetResponsibleEmployee(processInstance.ProcessId);
```

When I click compile I get the following error:

```
(1:27): error CS0103: The name 'AsperIo' does not exist in the current context
```

I was wondering whether anyone can help me figure out what seems to be the problem. Thanks.

Comment: What is AsperIo?, is it a static class? Is it on the same namespace?. Are you declaring the 'using' for the library on the top of your class?

Comment: Some `using` statement and/or library reference is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to register your type with the engine. Try calling the following method from the `WorkflowRuntime` object.

```
_runtime.RegisterAssemblyForCodeActions(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AsperIo.EmployeeProvider)));
```

Comment: Did the same not working for me.
runtime.RegisterAssemblyForCodeActions(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(PBWebModules.WorkflowEngine.MailActions)));
 I have created separate class MailActions and trying to call the methods inside the code actions.error below error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I also come across these kind of errors.In my case the target frame get conflicted. I had "netstandard2.0"
After changing the target frame to the below it started working.

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```